# How to develop a page like we see in regular apps?

Tags: tkinter

While I was using tkinter, it always opened up a completely new window upon clicking on an action. I wanted to know if there was some other way to code where the window will be the same and the changes will take place in there itself instead of opening a new window altogether separately. Is there a higher level of using tkinter for this? Or a separate module maybe?

Comment: You can destroy and recreate all of the widgets in a window. You don't need any additional modules. Have you tried just deleting the old widgets and adding new widgets?